# I'm getting the error "LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, linker-errors

Please help.
On Visual Studio 2008, I'm getting the following errors.

```
============================================================

   1>Microsoft (R) Windows Resource To Object Converter Version 9.00.30729.01
   1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
   1>adding resource. type:ICON, name:1, language:0x0409, flags:0x1010, size:744
   1>adding resource. type:ICON, name:2, language:0x0409, flags:0x1010, size:296
   1>adding resource. type:GROUP_ICON, name:128, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:34
   1>adding resource. type:DIALOG, name:100, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:374
   1>adding resource. type:DIALOG, name:102, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:784
   1>adding resource. type:VERSION, name:1, language:0x0409, flags:0x30, size:928
   1>adding resource. type:STRING, name:7, language:0x0409, flags:0x1030, size:68

   1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup

   1>.\Release/DiskTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

   1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\WinIRDir\Utilities\DiskTest\Release\BuildLog.htm"
   1>DiskTest - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
   1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\WinIRDir\Utilities\CommApp\Release\BuildLog.htm"
==============================================================
```

Here is the situation.
- DiskTest.exe is one of 3 projects in my solution
- This project builds perfectly for Debug x64, Release x64, and Debug Win32.  Release Win32 is the only one generating these errors.
- I have spend hours comparing the properties pages for all 4 config/machine combinations, and am confident that no properties are missing from one version to the next.  I paid special attention to  "Additional dependencies", "Additional Librari Directories", "Input", etc.  Ofcourse, paths to .lib files point to either \Debug or \Release, and \x86 or \x64 for the respective config or platform.

The only "additional dependency" this project has is SBF_Util.lib and SBF_Utild.lib for Debug.  I made sure that all 4 versions (debug win32 and x64, and Release win32 and x64) of this library exist in the folder specified in each "additional library directory"  I also checked dumpbin on each version of the library to make sure the platform matches.

I have seen other situations where a main entry point is missing, but in this case, all other versions build with no problems, it is only on Win32 Relase version that generates this error, so I don't think I need to change anything in the code.

Can anybody provide any clues?, I'm out of ideas.  Any ideas will be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the exact command line arguments that you're passing to the compiler? It sounds like you're compiling from Visual Studio, but it will show you in the "Advanced" tab what the command line is. Copy and paste that into your question using the [edit] link.

Comment: Also, check and make sure that *all* build configurations are targeting Unicode. My first instinct would be that the entry point function signature in your code is the non-Unicode version, but the libraries you're linking to in Release mode are the Unicode version. Hence, the linker can't find what it needs. But for that to make sense, all the *other* compilation modes would have to be targeting non-Unicode configurations, which seems unlikely.

Comment: This is the command line:/VERBOSE /OUT:".\Release/DiskTest.exe" /VERSION:3.800 /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\WinIRDir\SbfSdk\lib\x86\Release" /LIBPATH:"..\..\SbfSdk\lib\x86\Release" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:".\Release\DiskTest.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /DYNAMICBASE:NO /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT SBF_Util.lib


Additonal Options:
/version:3.607/subsystem:windows
/IGNORE:4089

Comment: I removed the "additional options", but still got the error.  Also, ALL modes use the "character set"= Multi-Byte (not unicode), even the other 2 projects in my solution they all use Multi-Byte.  I tried using Unicode on the failing mode (release/Win32) and on a "good" mode (release/x64), but I got C2664 errors on the good mode, and the same error on the failing mode, so I reverted back to Multi-Byte.

Comment: It's 2012 and you're still building apps targeting the MBCS?

Comment: I was facing similar issue,for me the solution was in processor directive i added _unicode ;unicode;Solved my problem...

Answer (score 6):

UNBELIEVABLE!!!

I found the problem!
It was an incredibly simple thing what was causing this criptic error: A "SPACE"

It turns out that under Configuration->C/C++->OutputFiles->Object File Name: I had:
"$(IntDir)\ "

Didn't notice the space until I paid very close attention to the Kdiff3 window, and noticed this tiny underscore to signal a space.
This space had been there for months, as this project had been left unattended (before I came on board), because nobody could find the fix for it, so they just stopped using it.
Most likely a copy-paste error.

Thank you all guys for your ideas. Specially the first answer from Xearinox that made me think about comparing all modes.  I'll try to find some time to write a tool to parse the project/solution files into a 4-column sheet that lists all properties for all configurations and platforms, so we can easily compare them.  Thank you all again.

Answer (score 3):

Open up your project's settings page, go to **Linker** → **System** and examine the **SubSystem** property.  Make sure it's set to the same value in all project configurations by switching the configuration from the configuration drop-down box.

Assuming that your intended entry point is `main` (or one of its variants such as `_tmain` or `wmain`), you want to make sure to use the SubSystem property is set to **CONSOLE**.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  However, Linker->System->Subsystem is set to Windows in all 4 configuration/platform combinations, but the other 3 combinations are linking fine with this setting, except for Release/Win32.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

WinMain as entry point is missing.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  How could we then explain that the debug (win32 and x64), and release/x64 modes are building correctly? The error shows up only when building Release win32.

Comment: I think somenthing is wrong in your Release win32 project options, please show me you linker command line.

Comment: After carefuly reading your post, I thing something is wrong with with CRT. If you set in linker /NODEFAULTLIB and /ENTRY:WinMain@16 and recompile, error still remains?

Comment: Just added /NODEFAULTLIB and /ENTRY:WinMain@16 to Linker->CommandLine->Additional Options.  Recompiled and got the same error.  I also went ahead and parsed the VC project file into separate text files for "release/wi32" and "release/x64", and then compared the 2 files with Kdiff3.  Both files look the same, exept for "Name", "target machine", "output directory", etc. (properties that obviously change from mode to mode).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file I was trying to compile had the wrong properties.

I had created the file with a stray character in the file extension, and so my project gave it the wrong Item Type: `Does not participate in build`.

After renaming it I went into its properties, and changed the Item Type to `<reset to default>`, which reset it to `C/C++ Compiler`.